# How to get last 4 weeks dates in power query (Excel or Power BI)

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

Using Power Query coding language AKA “m”, write a statement to add a custom column that shows a bit value of whether a Delivery Date is in the past 4 weeks including up to the current date.

Please #help
Result in blank query:
5/13/2021
5/12/2021
5/11/2021
5/10/2021
5/09/2021
Until
4/19/2021

Comment: Add some sample data and your expected output from them.

Comment: Added sample data

Comment: Is that delivery date?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correct, you need the custom column code-

```
if Duration.Days(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) - [Delivery date]) <= 28 then 1 else 0
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for reply. I need to get delivery date in the blank query. That is last 4 weeks dates from today date. The base date is today

Comment: Add you expected output.